# Stack Overflow error while finding common elements between two lists

Tags: groovy, stack-overflow

I have this code:

```
def input1 = ['a','b','e','r','t']
input2 = ['v','n','m','y']
ans = []

def common(def element,def i) {
  if (element == input2[i]) {
    ans << element
    return
  } else {
    common(element,++i)
  }
}  

for (i=0;i<input1.size();i++) {
  common(input1[i],0)
}
```

which is generating Stack Overflow error. Why is this happening?

#### Edit:

I'm trying to create my own way of finding common element between two lists.

Comment: The recursive call never terminates if it does not find a match. Piling up stack. I wonder if you should get ArrayOutOfBoundException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never check if `i` is greater than the length of `input2`, and in Groovy, getting beyond the length of a `List` returns `null`

So on the first element, it will keep looping round

```
if (element == input2[i]) {
```

for ever-increasing values of `i`, calling the `common` function every time, as it never matches `a`

Guessing at what you are trying to do, this can all be re-written as:

```
def input1 = ['a','b','e','r','t']
def input2 = ['v','n','m','y']
def ans = input1.intersect( input2 )
```

But it's hard to be sure what you want, and you dont explicitly say.

#### Edit

One method of deep recursion that avoids Stack Overflows is to use [Groovy's trampoline method](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/groovy-goodness-recursion-with-closure.html).

```
def common
common = { Object element, Collection list ->
  if( list.size() == 0 ) {                     // element not found.  Return null
    null
  }
  else if( list.head() == element ) {          // element found.  Return it
    element
  }
  else {
    common.trampoline( element, list.tail() )  // Trampoline down the list and check again
  }
}
common = common.trampoline()

def elements = ['a','b','e','v','r','t'].collect { // For each element in this list
                 common( it, ['v','n','m','y'] )   // Find if it's in our other list
               }.findAll()                         // And remove the nulls

assert elements == [ 'v' ]
```

But I'd still use `intersect` in this case, the above is just to show one of Groovy's ways you can avoid too-deep recursion...

Comment: @batman Then [intersect](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#intersect%28java.util.Collection%29) should do the job :-)

Comment: Yes , but I wish I could write one that is similar to `intersect` method ;)

Comment: How far back do you want to go?  `input1.findAll { input2.contains( it ) }` does the same thing too...  You want to rewrite `intersect` from first principles?  Here's the [function as it is written in Groovy](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L7792)

Comment: Not to mention the "intersect" operation and/or the "findAll" operation don't really lend themselves well to a recursive solution.  And if you wanted to use recursion, a tail recursive algorithm would be better anyway.  I'm not sure if groovy will optimize for tail recursion, but it's still usually more efficient to have a collector than to constantly be creating new lists and appending to them.

Comment: @Matt added a function that uses `trampoline`.  Obviously, `intersect` should still be used in its place, but I thought it might be interesting to try ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code doesn't stop when reaches the end of array input2. If element is not in input2 then it will keep making recursive calls **common(element,++i)** forever which results in stack overflow error.